# Change html click event to show inner html c#

Tags: html, css

Can anyone tell me how I can show the inner html when one of the icons in this website is clicked? aka the assets.

[Example](http://www.roblox.com/ide/clienttoolbox)

Comment: Why tag this as c#..?

Comment: i would like to make it to call a c# function if possible @CapnJack

Comment: I'm really confused, you're going to have to give more background in your question if you want answers. This sounds like a simple JS solution involving and CSS show/hide on an element ID click(). Did you try that? Also using the Roblox website is sort of weird as an example..

Comment: I agree. you should tag this Question with CSS or JS. Otherwise, most probably you will not get the best answer since CSS and JS expert will not check your question.

Answer (score 0):

Note: Inner Html is content of html tag
 ex:

hello

=> hello is inner html

but based on your example you are looking for how to add/remove UI element to/from the screen.

You can use C# for it, But this is the **wrongest** choice. because of server unnecessary load and bad UX-UI for the client.

The best option is using CSS and CSS based animation to make it fancy. check this for animation. [animationcss](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)
key for your solution is looking for css hover if you exactly looking for same ehavior as example or use js click to add css class to your element.

```js
$("#clickItem").click(() => {
  $(".hiddenContent2").toggleClass("showThis");
});
```

```css
.hiddenContent1 , .hiddenContent2{
  visibility: hidden;
}

.item{
  cursor:pointer;
  border:1px solid red;
  margin:5px;
  padding:10px;
  width:200px;
}

#hoverItem:hover .hiddenContent1 {
  visibility: visible;
}

.showThis{
  visibility:visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://raw.github.com/daneden/animate.css/master/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="hoverItem" class="item">
  <h4>item hover</h4>
  <div class="hiddenContent1">
    <p>hidden elements</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="clickItem" class="item">
  <h4>item click</h4>
  <div class="hiddenContent2">
    <p>hidden elements</p>
  </div>
</div>
```